# when i am using javascript function to get elemen by class it shows me [object HTMLCollection] not the value inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have also convert the variable s to string but the result is same what to do how to get the value by class.

```
function myFunction() {
   var s = document.getElementsByClassName('clinic-timings-day');
   alert(s);
   document.getElementById('#mine').innerHTML = s[0].toString();
   alert("test2");
}

<body>
   <p class="clinic-timings-day">MON, WED</p>
   <a onclick="myFunction()">Try it</a>
</body>
```

Comment: that selector is returning an array. you will have to loop through the array to see the content for the div you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your made few mistakes on your function.

```
  var s = document.getElementsByClassName('clinic-timings-day').innerHTML;

  document.getElementById('mine').innerHTML = s[0].toString();
```